# Powershell batch command: Cannot escape backslash by doubling it when using "notlike"?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, batch

This Powershell command works in a batch file to remove all lines from `%tempFile%` that contain the text string `foo`

```
powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "gci %tempFile% | foreach { (cat $_.FullName | ? { $_ -notlike '*foo*' }) | set-content $_.FullName -Force }"
```

The `-notlike` command does also work without using asterisks:

```
| ? { $_ -notlike 'foo' }) |
```

I have lines in `%tempFile%` that contain a backslash character `\` and want those lines removing. The usual solution is to double up the backslash character to escape it like this `\\` and while that does work when using replace commands, it doesn't work for me when I am using the above `-notlike` command.

None of these examples work:

```
powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "gci %tempFile% | foreach { (cat $_.FullName | ? { $_ -notlike '*\\*' }) | set-content $_.FullName -Force }"
powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "gci %tempFile% | foreach { (cat $_.FullName | ? { $_ -notlike '*\*' }) | set-content $_.FullName -Force }"
powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "gci %tempFile% | foreach { (cat $_.FullName | ? { $_ -notlike '\\' }) | set-content $_.FullName -Force }"
powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "gci %tempFile% | foreach { (cat $_.FullName | ? { $_ -notlike '\' }) | set-content $_.FullName -Force }"
```

I wonder why?

Thanks in advance to anyone that can shed some light on this one.

Comment: The PowerShell escape character is the grave-accent(`\``)

Comment: That won't work when it's being escaped in a batch file like this is. I don't want to use `.ps1` scripts. When I use `-replace` to replace the backslash character (with the command in a batch file) that works fine. It's just not working when I'm trying to remove lines containing a backslash as in this case.

Comment: If it's a batch file then try using the batch escape `^`

Comment: The reason replace works with "\\" is that it uses [regular expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions) where as `like` uses [wildcard expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards) (different syntax and escape methods)

Comment: David thanks, but that doesn't escape it. In all previous cases, escaping a special character is done by either doubling it, or putting a \ before it, or in the case of a double quote it's four of them `""""`. There's a few others like `","` to escape a comma. I have tried probably 15 different ways, including: \\\\ and "\" and many others. @jfrmilner cheers... is it even possible to escape it using `notlike`?

Comment: Do you need to read the actual command in the file, as in, it could be base64 encoded. I could provide an example if needed.

Comment: I've just tried line two `'*\*'` and it worked as expected for me (no escape needed). I used `cmd` to run the `bat` file containing the PowerShell code.

Answer (score 0):

```bath
@echo off

>"%temp%\Q1767780.txt" ^
    (
     echo+ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Qui magnam adipisci id officiis 
     echo+ temporibus non minima molestias ex animi tempora et eveniet atque.
     echo\ Et ratione unde qui numquam libero est voluptas nesciunt.\
     echo+ 
     echo\ Id \corporis dolorum vel debitis dolore ut voluptas temporibus est 
     echo+ obcaecati harum eos earum fugit et reprehenderit temporibus eos 
     echo\ voluptas vero.\
     echo\               \
    ) && set "_tempFile=%temp%\Q1767780.txt"

PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "$Strs=(cat "%_tempFile%" | sls -Not '\\'); sc "%_tempFile%" $Strs -Force"
     
type "%_tempFile%"
```

---

- Result in:

```bath
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Qui magnam adipisci id officis
 temporibus non minima molestias ex animi tempora et eveniet atque.

 obcaecati harum eos earum fugit et reprehenderit temporibus eos
```

---

Use `cat` to store the contents of the file by subtracting lines with the `\` character, which can be escaped with adicional `\  ===>  \\`.

And try replace `... -notlike '\\'` to `... -NotMatch '\\'` or `... -Not '\\'`

---

## **[Select-String / sls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7.3)**

- Short description:

The comparison operators in PowerShell can either compare two values
or filter elements of a collection against an input value.

- Long description:

Comparison operators let you compare values or finding values that
match specified patterns. PowerShell includes the following
comparison operators:

- Equality

```bath
-eq, -ieq, -ceq - equals
-ne, -ine, -cne - not equals
-gt, -igt, -cgt - greater than
-ge, -ige, -cge - greater than or equal
-lt, -ilt, -clt - less than
-le, -ile, -cle - less than or equal
```

- Matching

```bath
-like, -ilike, -clike - string matches wildcard pattern
-notlike, -inotlike, -cnotlike - string doesn't match wildcard pattern
-match, -imatch, -cmatch - string matches regex pattern
-notmatch, -inotmatch, -cnotmatch - string doesn't match regex pattern
```

---